# Recoding for component API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

How would I write this for composition API using Vue 3?

```
  checkboxFilter:{genre: [], moods: [], tempo: [], theme: []},


    computed: {

    filteredSongs: function(value, key){
    let fltrdSongs = this.songs;
    if(this.checkboxFilter.genre.length + this.checkboxFilter.moods.length + this.checkboxFilter.tempo.length + this.checkboxFilter.theme.length > 0) {
      // checking if "genre" array has elements
      if (this.checkboxFilter.genre.length > 0) {
        fltrdSongs = this.songs.filter((song) => {
          let length = this.checkboxFilter.genre.length;
          while(length--){
            if ((song.genre).indexOf(this.checkboxFilter.genre[length])!=-1) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        });
      }
      if(this.checkboxFilter.moods.length > 0) {
        fltrdSongs = fltrdSongs.filter((song) => {
          let length = this.checkboxFilter.moods.length;
          while(length--){
            if ((song.moods).indexOf(this.checkboxFilter.moods[length])!=-1) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        });
      }
      if(this.checkboxFilter.tempo.length > 0) {
        fltrdSongs = fltrdSongs.filter((song) => {
          let length = this.checkboxFilter.tempo.length;
          while(length--){
            if ((song.tempo).indexOf(this.checkboxFilter.tempo[length])!=-1) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        });
      }
      if(this.checkboxFilter.theme.length > 0) {
        fltrdSongs = fltrdSongs.filter((song) => {
          let length = this.checkboxFilter.theme.length;
          while(length--){
            if ((song.theme).indexOf(this.checkboxFilter.theme[length])!=-1) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }

    return fltrdSongs.filter((song) => {
      return song.keywords.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
             song.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
             song.description.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
      });
   },
```

I am attempting to change my website to the composition api format but I can't seem to get the checkboxes to filter as I want. I have already attempted to rewrite this but the problem I kept having was that each genre, mood, theme and tempo would only return the first string in the respective sections of the array of songs. What I want is to select a genre checkbox and have all tracks return that genre, even if it is number three in the genre list. At the moment it will only return the first one. Here is where I got to:

```
const searchTerm = ref('')

 const genreFilter = ref([])
 const moodsFilter = ref([])
  const tempoFilter = ref([])
  const themeFilter = ref([])

const filteredTracks = computed(() => {
 let filtered = useSong.tracks;

 if (searchTerm.value) {
const term = searchTerm.value.toLowerCase();
filtered = filtered.filter(track =>
  track.description.toLowerCase().includes(term) || 
  track.genre.toLowerCase().includes(term) ||
  track.keywords.toLowerCase().includes(term) ||
  track.moods.toLowerCase().includes(term)
);
}

 if (genreFilter.value.length > 0) {
filtered = filtered.filter(track => genreFilter.value.includes(track.genre))
}

if (moodsFilter.value.length > 0) {
filtered = filtered.filter(track => moodsFilter.value.includes(track.moods))
}

if (tempoFilter.value.length > 0) {
filtered = filtered.filter(track => tempoFilter.value.includes(track.tempo))
}

if (themeFilter.value.length > 0) {
filtered = filtered.filter(track => themeFilter.value.includes(track.theme))
}

return filtered;
 });
```

Thanks in advance.

Here is a link to the majority of the code:
[SFC for the pages/components](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Could please include more complete code for the first block? What is `checkboxFilter`, for example?

Comment: A decent [mre] post would go a long way towards making this question easier to answer. Also, use the [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/).

Comment: I'll add a link to the SFC Playground in the original post above. The tracks are stored in a json file and imported into a pinia store. I have added the song.js for the Pinia store, the SongRow component and the MusicView page as well ass the vue app.

Comment: What are some example values for something like `track`?  Can you give details on what an expected filter result looks like vs the actual result you're seeing (as in specific object/array values)?

Comment: @yoduh I want the checkbox filters for genres, moods, etc. (rock, orchestral, inspirational, funny etc.) to go through the array of tracks and return all tracks with these words included. Here is an example of the json and how tracks are stored. Some tracks have multiple genres or moods but they won't return in the v-for filteredTracks. Only the first word is taken and returned. So in the json example, the song Ab Aeterno will return when epic trailer is selected but not when orchestral is selected. I hope this makes sense. [json example](https://codepen.io/parca0007/pen/YzOoWwy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter is not successful because track.genre is a comma separated string of multiple genres.  Say your selected filters were "Rock" and "Pop" and your track has genre "Pop, Rock".  Your filter is then trying to do:

```js
["Rock", "Pop"].includes("Pop, Rock") // no match found
```

The filter would only produce a match here if the genreFilter included the entire string being tested, e.g.

```
["Rock", "Pop", "Pop, Rock"].includes("Pop, Rock") // 1 match found
```

One possible strategy to deal with this is to convert the string `"Pop, Rock"` into an array of strings using [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) then test every value in that array against every value in the genreFilter array.  Using [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) you can do it like this:

```js
if (genreFilter.value.length > 0) {
  const trackGenres = track.genre.split(', ');
  filtered = filtered.filter(track =>
    genreFilter.value.some(g => trackGenres.includes(g))
  );
}
```

One pitfall to watch out for is that *every* track with multiple genres needs to be separated exactly by comma space `", "`.  If the JSON is missing a space between commas, or a genre has a comma as part of its name, you'll get a bad result and you'll need to rethink how you split and/or take into consideration special cases.

Comment: Thanks @yoduh but when I add the string split and array some it doesn't work at all, unfortunately. Strange thing is it worked fine before when it was all in one page with a js file instead of a json file being imported into Pinia. Could it be something to do with the way that is setup? I will add the Pinia setup in the original question.

Comment: Pinia is the song.js in the SFC